# libspatialite.so for 64 Bit Linux

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, pythonanywhere, spatialite

Hi I am using spatialite extension functions for one of my select Query as below.

```
con.enable_load_extension(True)
con.execute('SELECT load_extension("libspatialite")')
........
con.enable_load_extension(False)
```

I am enocuntering error as below:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: libspatialite-linux-x86-2.3.1/lib/libspatialite.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

I figured out the root cause ,For this I need to have 64bit version of spatialite. Currently running 32bit one.

But I am unable to find 64 version libspatialite (have spent lot of time on this), is there any way to fix this issue ?

Comment: Some distributions package spatialite. You could also compile it from sources yourself.